# logical anding of pointer with an integer

Tags: c, pointers

I was studying the LwIP Ethernet stack and I saw the following code in the `netif.c` file which is :

```
if (ipaddr && (ip_addr_cmp(ipaddr, &(netif->ip_addr))) == 0)
```

Here there is a logical comparison between pointer and an integer which I am not able to recall but some time back actually I googled it and found out that it is a smart way of checking a null pointer, but not able to get that link right now , so any of you guys if know the link or have any description regarding this , than please try to provide me that.

Comment: There is no logical comparison between any pointer and integer. There is a logical AND. Which is used to short circuit the call if ipaddr is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ipaddr && (ip_addr_cmp(ipaddr, &(netif->ip_addr))) == 0)
```

This just means that proceed to call `ip_addr_cmp`, if and only if `ipaddr` is not NULL.

If the statement is modified as below with same meaning, it might have been more clear to you.

```
if ((ipaddr != NULL) && (ip_addr_cmp(ipaddr, &(netif->ip_addr))) == 0)
```